# What cable do I need to connect an SPI (4-wire) interface?

Tags: spi, cable

I have received an [e-ink display](https://www.waveshare.com/1.54inch-e-paper.htm) as a gift. The connection interface is SPI. I would assume that I need to find a cable/adaptor that would output to different GPIO (I have a breadboard so it should be easy). My search has been unsuccessful so far.

Could someone clarify how would I connect this to the Raspberry? Any link pointing to the exact cable for example would be helpful.

Below is the picture of display:
[image: e-ink display]

Comment: Please add details of your e-ink display to your question

Comment: I’ve added it. I was unsure if it’d been considered spam but I understand it helps for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry PI GPIO uses 100 mil spacing dual row header like in the picture below:

[image: pin header]

At the moment it is unclear what kind of connector is there on your e-ink display. Assuming that you have a similar kind of connector, you can use DuPont cables to wire up your display. DuPont cables are pretty cheap and abundant on eBay. A picture of DuPont wires is below:

[image]

Here is the GPIO pinout of Raspberry Pi:

[image: Raspberry Pi GPIO Pinout]

According to the pinout, you have to use the following SPI pins:

```
GPIO10 - SPI0_MOSI
GPIO9  - SPI0 MISO
GPIO11 - SPI0 SCLK
GPIO8  - SPI CE0 N (optional if only one device on bus)
```

Please do elaborate your question so that this answer can be more precise to your question.

EDIT:
From your addition it looks like that your display uses FPC cable. One option you have is to manually solder SPI wires to the FPC cable if you possess soldering finesse. Otherwise, you would have to design a PCB that incorporates a FPC connector and header pins. Check with the manufacturer if they offer any conversion options (see below picture):
[image: Conversion]

Comment: I have added the specific display to my question. I believe these cables cannot be used in my case. Would you mind checking the display and update your suggestion if possible?